# Excepción cada vez que intento crear una nueva fila en SQL con Java

Tags: java

he estado recibiendo un error que es el siguiente:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Me he puesto a investigar por internet y todos coincidían en que después de un scanner hay que poner un **scanner.next();**. El caso es que funciona hasta que quiero crear una tercera fila que me vuelve a dar el mismo problema.

Este es el fragmento de código, que pertenece a un switch:

```
case 1: //CREAR NUEVO SUPERGUERRERO
                   System.out.print("Nombre de superguerrero: ");
                   guerrero = scan.next();
                   System.out.print("Descripcion de superguerrero: ");
                   descripcion = scan.next();
                   
                   scan.next();     //Es aquí donde ví que había que poner el scanner
                   
                   System.out.print("Poder de fuego: ");
                   fuego = scan.nextInt();       //Y es aquí cuando me da el error mencionado
                   System.out.print("Poder de agua: ");
                   agua = scan.nextInt();
                   System.out.print("Poder de viento: ");
                   viento = scan.nextInt();
                   
                   if (fuego > 5 || fuego < 1 || agua > 5 || agua < 1 || viento > 5 || viento < 1) {
                       System.out.println("Los poderes deben ser del 1 al 5");
                       break;
                       
                   } else {
                       stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO superespecie VALUES(null, '"+guerrero+"', '"+descripcion+"', '"+fuego+"', '"+agua+"', '"+viento+"')");
                       break;
                       
                   }
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, he encontrado mi problema.
No se trata de un **scanner.next();**

Debe ser un **scanner.nextLine();**